# Detecting Emacs window is already split

Tags: emacs, configuration, elisp

How do I detect that an Emacs window has already been split?

In my `.emacs` file, I have:

```
(when (display-graphic-p)
  (set-frame-size (selected-frame) 166 85)
  (split-window-horizontally))
```

which allows me to have two buffers side-by-side, each exactly 80 chars wide.

Every once in a while I change my .emacs file and want to reload it in place, so I run `M-x load-file` on my .emacs file and that window I'm in gets re-split.

Is there some sort of command I can call to check if the frame has already been split and only call `(split-window-horizontally)` if it hasn't? Something like:

```
(when (window-is-root)
  (split-window-horizontally))
```

or

```
(when (not (window-is-already-split))
  (split-window-horizontally))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`window-list` will return you a list of the windows (for the current frame), so you should be able to do:

```
(when (= (length (window-list)) 1)
  (split-window-horizontally))
```

Check out the [relevant documentation for windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Windows-and-Frames.html#Windows-and-Frames).

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! And thanks for the documentation pointer as well. I found this page: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Splitting-Windows.html#Splitting-Windows but it didn't seem to have any useful information.

Answer (score -3):

This is a meaningless questions, windows are not split.

Yes, there are functions named split-window..., but what they do is merely to reduce the size of the window, and create a new one in the space thus freed.

You cannot just use (= 1 (length (window-list))) since you have at least one window per frame (not counting the simili-window of the minibuffer).

You could try:

```
(< (length (frame-list)) (length (window-list)))
```

but that doesn't tell you if there are several windows in the selected frame, which is what you are actually asking, since obviously it could be another frame that contains several windows.

So if you ask the question CORRECTLY, "how can I know whether the selected frame contains more than one window", you can easily find the answer:

```
(require 'cl)

(defun complement (fun)
  (byte-compile `(lambda (&rest args) (not (apply ',fun args)))))

(defun* more-than-one-window-in-frame-p (&optional (frame (selected-frame)))
  (< 1 (length (remove* frame (window-list)
                        :key (function window-frame)
                        :test (complement (function eql))))))
```

Comment: Function: window-list &optional frame minibuffer window.
This function returns a list of live windows belonging to the frame frame. If frame is omitted or nil, it defaults to the selected frame. So it only returns the windows in this frame. I tried `(= (length (window-list)) 1)` with two frames and it works fine.

Comment: From: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Windows-and-Frames.html#Windows-and-Frames